# Using grep to find words

Tags: shell, unix, grep

> Find the lines in alice.txt that contain at least 17 words.
>
> Hint 1: To check whether a word has ended, look for the following
>   characters: `[, ; : ’ .]`(note that there is also a space in the list)
>
> Hint 2: Your code should return 13 lines

First attempt outputs 15 words instead of 17 and has 13 lines
Second attempt doesn't output anything but I think the overall idea is correct unless I'm missing something...

First Attempt:

```
grep -Ein "([a-z]+[, ;:'\.]){15,}" alice.txt
```

Second Attempt:

```
grep -Ein "(\b[a-z]+\b){17,}" alice.txt
```

Expected the results to be correct, but only resulted in 15 modifiers instead of the 17 that was asked for in the problem.  Code, however, returns 13 lines

Comment: [edit] your question to include a sample of `alice.txt` otherwise we have nothing to test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd really do this in UNIX using GNU awk for FPAT:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\w+' 'NF>16'
```

for example:

```
$ echo 'foo bar, etc.' | awk -v FPAT='\\w+' '{print NF}'
3
$ echo 'foo bar, etc.' | awk -v FPAT='\\w+' 'NF>2'
foo bar, etc.
$ echo 'foo bar, etc.' | awk -v FPAT='\\w+' 'NF>3'
$
```